# Grouping text and values in Visual Basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to make the grouping of by the first column, and the values of the elements of the second column at the specified groups.

```
Option Compare Database
Sub lab9()
    Dim vmas(11, 1) As Variant
    vmas(0, 0) = red
    vmas(1, 0) = red
    vmas(2, 0) = black
    vmas(3, 0) = black
    vmas(4, 0) = red
    vmas(5, 0) = blue
    vmas(6, 0) = blue
    vmas(7, 0) = black
    vmas(8, 0) = blue
    vmas(9, 0) = blue
    vmas(10, 0) = black
    vmas(11, 0) = black

    vmas(0, 1) = 3
    vmas(1, 1) = 6
    vmas(2, 1) = 5
    vmas(3, 1) = 9
    vmas(4, 1) = 1
    vmas(5, 1) = 6
    vmas(6, 1) = 3
    vmas(7, 1) = 11
    vmas(8, 1) = 10
    vmas(9, 1) = 1
    vmas(10, 1) = 3
    vmas(11, 1) = 2

    Dim sum As Variant
    For i = 0 To 1 Step 1
    sum = 0
    For j = 0 To 10 Step 1
        sum = sum + vmas(j, i)
    Next j
    vmas(11, i) = sum
    Next i
Dim sql1 As Variant
sql1 = "create table result (ResultName char ,ResultSum integer )"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql1
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO result VALUES( '" & vmas(11, 0) & "' , " & vmas(11, 1) & "         )")
DoCmd.OpenTable "result", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
MsgBox "Result work in table. Table close"
DoCmd.Close acTable, "result"

DoCmd.RunSQL ("drop table result")
End Sub
```

How can i do it this?

Comment: Please revise your question to include expected output and what you've tried to reach that output. As is, it's difficult to understand what you're asking...

Comment: I need to first column in the array grouped(for example, if there are three entries "red" remained one entry) and in the second column was the sum of the numbers which are among the "red".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to end up adding rows to a two column table. The first column is the unique color names and the second column is a sum of the associated values in vmas(x, 1). Here are the first two options that come to mind:

Recordsets (more overhead but less thought):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tmpTbl"
For i = 0 to UBound(vmas)
    ' Insert Row Into tmpTbl
Next i
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO result(ResultName, ResultSum) SELECT ResultName, Sum(ResultSum) FROM tmpTbl GROUP BY ResultName"
```

Custom Logic (VBA's support of dynamic lists is extremely limited so we'll use an array):
  Something like...

```
Dim mySumArray() As Object
For i = 0 to UBound(vmas)
    ' If Color does not exist in 2-D mySumArray
    '     ReDim Preserve mySumArray(UBound(mySumArray) + 1, 1)
    ' Else
    '     Add the current number to the total for that color
    ' End If
Next i
For j = 0 to UBound(mySumArray)
    ' Insert Row Into result table
Next j
```

You could do the Custom Logic option with a string array and an integer array. I probably would just because of VBA's limitations.

More concisely and avoiding additional arrays... (Can eliminate first WHERE clause if ResultName forced to be unique).

```
For i = 0 to UBound(vmas)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO result (ResultName, ResultSum) VALUES ('" & vmas(i,0) & "', 0) WHERE '" vmas(i, 0) & "' Not In (SELECT ResultName FROM result);"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE result SET ResultSum = ResultSum + " & vmas(i, 1) & " WHERE ResultName = '" vmas(i, 0) & "';"
Next i
```

Did I answer your question?

Comment: Everything correctly. But before that I need to make the array, and then to group colors and add up the numbers, and at the end of the record in the table.

Comment: You already created the original 2D array in your code sample. That is necessary of course. Are you referring to the array containing the sums?? The custom logic option creates that array without originally actually knowing how many colors there are. It just adds an item to the array every time it finds a color it doesn't already have in the array and keeps running tallies. Ideally in another language you'd do this with perhaps a dictionary<string, int>. Then you could do Dictionary.ContainsKey(vmas(i,0)).

Comment: And to continue my last comment, the recordset option doesn't need to initally create an array containing the sums (temp table plus GROUP BY query handles that) unless you have some other use for that array. But then you could just get it as a recordset after all is said and done.

Comment: Today is the first time I work with Visual Basic.
And the problem is that I do not understand how it should be in the result.

Comment: Ok. What are you planning to use the output for?? Or is this just a learning exercise where the goal is to get the sums but they will never need to be used?

Comment: Okay. "I do not understand how it should be in the result"...You have to decide what defines exercise completion. Do you want the sums stored in a table, printed to the screen, just in an array in memory, or written to a file? There is no right answer I can give you for that question.

Comment: These data should be stored in a table, the first column will be the colors and the second is the amount of numbers. I don't understand how to look at the code.

Comment: So the methods I presented are (in plain English):
1) Add all data to a temporary table that you only use as an intermediate step. Then use a SQL query to perform the grouping and insert into your output table.
2) Or do the logic yourself by stepping through your array keeping running totals. You can keep these running totals in an array or you output table.

Comment: If you changed your create table statement to force ResultName to be unique you could do your running totals in the output table without ever bothering to check if something exists yet.

Comment: If i understand correctly that code must be such as https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78407143/123.txt

Comment: Well basically yes but you have two of my methods in your code. I presented three alternative code blocks NOT to be used together. Either write the actual programming code inside the two for loops below 'Dim sum As Variant' (I wrote pseudocode comments in them above) or eliminate that and just use the part below (but put those two DoCmd.RunSQL statements back in a 0 to 11 loop as I did in my third code sample.

Comment: My apologies, but I did not understand what should be the code. If you have the opportunity, please write it in a text file.

Comment: Attached is the compiled code for my third method: [Grouping Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/giptdint9g9255b/GroupData_Concise.txt)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work unfortunately. 
Error "3067" - as input a query must have at least one table or query.

Comment: It's possible I messed up the queries since I don't have a database in front of me.  Does it help to change DoCmd.RunSQL to CurrentDb.Execute?

Comment: Please take a look at my database. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78407143/Petikov%20S.%20group%20206%2C%20KR8.accdb
I work in Module1.

Comment: Okay here you go. The method main_grouping_method sets up your initial array. It then calls three different methods of solving your problem: calcSums1, calcSums2, and calcSums3. The results of those three methods are stored in the tables result, result2, and result3. I also have a function down at the bottom that I use to close and delete existing tables.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/27aw6ssd8sx7h20/Petikov%20S.%20group%20206%2C%20KR8.accdb